# Enable YellowBox in apk build

Tags: react-native

How to build `apk` that shows `YellowBox` like the app in dev mode?

Comment: I think you can not, that's only available in development mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you can not enable it in Apk build but possible in development mode.** 
But if you really need this you can create a component and put it in the bottom position.
If your response in the JSON format than convert it in the string also.
and **let me know if i can do some other help :)**